# Centering rotated text in a table header with bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

In Bootstrap 4 I'm struggling with positioning rotated text in a table header.
Ideally I want all the rotated text to be aligned with the bottom of the cell, and centered horizontally.
I have tried different transform-origins but center seems to be the right one?

Any idea why the cell text for the rotated headers is outside the bounds of the cell borders?

```css
.table-rotated-header {
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; width: 100%;">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th colspan="5" class="text-center">
        <h3>Paint</h3</th>
          <th colspan="2" class="text-center">
            <h3>Wheels</h3>
          </th>
          <th colspan="2" class="text-center">
            <h3>Interior</h3>
          </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th nowrap class="table-rotated-header">
        <h5>Country</h5>
      </th>
      <th nowrap class="table-rotated-header">
        <h5>White</h5>
      </th>
      <th nowrap class="table-rotated-header">
        <h5>Red</h5>
      </th>
      <th nowrap class="table-rotated-header">
        <h5>Blue</h5>
      </th>
      <th nowrap class="table-rotated-header">
        <h5>Black</h5>
      </th>
      <th nowrap class="table-rotated-header">
        <h5>Yellow</h5>
      </th>
      <th nowrap class="table-rotated-header">
        <h5>18&quot; Spider</h5>
      </th>
      <th nowrap class="table-rotated-header">
        <h5>19&quot; Sport</h5>
      </th>
      <th nowrap class="table-rotated-header">
        <h5>Black</h5>
      </th>
      <th nowrap class="table-rotated-header">
        <h5>White</h5>
      </th>

    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>South Korea</td>
      <td class="text-end">$10,400</td>
      <td class="text-end">$900</td>
      <td class="text-end">$0</td>
      <td class="text-end">$0</td>
      <td class="text-end">Included</td>
      <td class="text-end">$900</td>
      <td class="text-end">$12,200</td>
      <td class="text-end">$6000</td>
      <td class="text-end">$6000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try a flex approach :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Rotated Table Header</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        /* CSS for Rotated Table Header */
        .table-rotated-header {
            writing-mode: vertical-rl; /* Vertical text */
            text-orientation: mixed; /* Maintain horizontal layout */
            white-space: nowrap;
            text-align: center;
        }

        /* Style the table as needed */
        .table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }

        /* Additional styling for cells */
        .table th,
        .table td {
            border: 1px solid #ccc; /* Add borders for better visualization */
            padding: 8px; /* Add padding for cell content */
            text-align: center; /* Center text horizontally */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <th>
                    <h3>Paint</h3>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <h3>Wheels</h3>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <h3>Interior</h3>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <h5>Country</h5>
                </th>
                <th class="table-rotated-header">White</th>
                <th class="table-rotated-header">Red</th>
                <th class="table-rotated-header">Blue</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>South Korea</td>
                <td class="text-center">$10,400</td>
                <td class="text-center">$900</td>
                <td class="text-center">$0</td>
            </tr>
            <!-- Add more rows as needed -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit after comment :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Rotated Table Header</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        /* CSS for Rotated Table Header */
        .table-rotated-header {
            writing-mode: vertical-rl; /* Vertical text */
            text-orientation: mixed; /* Maintain horizontal layout */
            white-space: nowrap;
            text-align: center;
            transform: rotate(180deg);
            text-orientation: mixed; /* Maintain horizontal layout */

        }

        /* Style the table as needed */
        .table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }

        /* Additional styling for cells */
        .table th,
        .table td {
            border: 1px solid #ccc; /* Add borders for better visualization */
            padding: 8px; /* Add padding for cell content */
            text-align: center; /* Center text horizontally */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <th>
                    <h3>Paint</h3>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <h3>Wheels</h3>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <h3>Interior</h3>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <h5>Country</h5>
                </th>
                <th class="table-rotated-header">White</th>
                <th class="table-rotated-header">Red</th>
                <th class="table-rotated-header">Blue</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>South Korea</td>
                <td class="text-center">$10,400</td>
                <td class="text-center">$900</td>
                <td class="text-center">$0</td>
            </tr>
            <!-- Add more rows as needed -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  That mostly worked as I hoped.  I did want the text to be rotated 180 degreese from how you presented it.  Is there a writing-mode that accomplishes that?  Secondly, how do I get the vertical text aligned in the middle horizontally?

Comment: I edited the post for a 180degrees rotation. But for centering it seems that there is some css limitations.. Still not working even with a 'vertical-align: middle;'

Comment: When I did 'vertical-align:middle !important;' I got it to work.